# After refresh the page image is not show in the view in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

[image]I have to upload a image in AnguarJS using firebase but problem is that the image is properly uploaded as well as i have to store the imageURL into the localStorage but after refresh the page image is remove i don't uderstand what the problem

```js
$scope.backgroundImageURL  = [];
$scope.currentUserObject   = {};
$scope.uploadBackgroundImage = function(event) {
//Get the userDetail of the current logged in user
$scope.currentUserObject =  localStorage.getItem('userName');

   //Get the value from the input field and assign into the fireabse node
   var userProductImg       = $("#getImageAttribute")[0].files[0];
   var PRODUCT_STORAGE_REF  = firebase.storage().ref('user/image');

   //get the date as well as put the imageURL from node
  var rn = new Date().getTime().toString();
  var task =              PRODUCT_STORAGE_REF.child("loggedInUserObject").child($scope.currentUserObject).child(rn).put(userProductImg).then(function(snapshot) {
      
      $timeout(function(){
           $scope.backgroundImageURL.push(snapshot.downloadURL);
          localStorage.setItem('userImageURL', $scope.backgroundImageURL);
       }, 50);
  })
 }
```

```html
<input type="file" id="getImageAttribute" ng-click="$event = $event" ng-      model="display" multiple                  onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadBackgroundImage(event)"
/>
<span ng-repeat="imgURL in backgroundImageURL"> 
<img src="{{imgURL}}">
</span>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

try using `ng-src` instead of `src` attribute as it will refresh the image if the there is a dynamic change in bacground img url.

You can more about this from here: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-src.asp 
or 
you can try this too : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: Its not working for me sir after refresh the page image is removed again after using ng-src?

Answer (score 0):

After refresh the page, your image array is empty:

> `$scope.backgroundImageURL  = [];`

You need a method to get images from the storage and assign them to your backgroundImageURL array, and this method has to be called as soon as you load the page.

Your code might be something like the following:

```
$scope.backgroundImageURL  = [];
$scope.currentUserObject   = {};

$scope.loadResources();

$scope.loadResources = function() {
  $scope.backgroundImageURL = localStorage.getItem('userImageURL');
  $scope.currentUserObject = localStorage.getItem('userName');
}

$scope.uploadBackgroundImage = function(event) {
//Get the userDetail of the current logged in user
$scope.currentUserObject =  localStorage.getItem('userName');

   //Get the value from the input field and assign into the fireabse node
   var userProductImg       = $("#getImageAttribute")[0].files[0];
   var PRODUCT_STORAGE_REF  = firebase.storage().ref('user/image');

   //get the date as well as put the imageURL from node
  var rn = new Date().getTime().toString();
  var task =              PRODUCT_STORAGE_REF.child("loggedInUserObject").child($scope.currentUserObject).child(rn).put(userProductImg).then(function(snapshot) {

      $timeout(function(){
           $scope.backgroundImageURL.push(snapshot.downloadURL);
          localStorage.setItem('userImageURL', $scope.backgroundImageURL);
       }, 50);
  })
 }
```

Comment: Sir after load the page imagURL is get but in the home page image is not show again multiple times array is iterated in case i have only 1 imgeURL is found check the my updated fiddle with  console.